# Can I mount a light fixture on an electrical outlet box?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, structural, support

I have a backyard with no light but we do have an outdoor outlet. I would like to know if I can mount a light fixture using the electrical outlet box. The mounting plate comes with the light fixture, and I am able to screw the mounting plate to the electrical outlet box. I am not entirely sure if the outlet junction box is structurally strong to support the light fixture. What are your thoughts?
The light fixture weight about 4 pounds.

[image]

[image]

[image]